# How to release memory created from CFStringTokenizerCreate?

Tags: iphone, core-foundation

I use CFRelease to release the CFStringTokenizerRef obtained from CFStringTokenizerCreate call.  But instruments is reporting memory leak at around this area.  Am I missing something?

```
  CFStringTokenizerRef tokenRef = CFStringTokenizerCreate(NULL, 
                                   (CFStringRef)contents, 
                                   CFRangeMake(0, contents.length),
                                   kCFStringTokenizerUnitWordBoundary, 
                                   NULL);

  CFStringTokenizerTokenType tokenType;
  // leak reported here
  while ((tokenType = CFStringTokenizerAdvanceToNextToken(tokenRef)) != kCFStringTokenizerTokenNone) 

}

CFRelease(tokenRef);
```

Comment: There seems to be a missing brace after the while, this the CFRelease is not in the same scope. Is it a copy/paste error ?

Answer (score 0):

CFStringTokenizerCreate follows the [Create Rule](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029). So you are calling as expected.

There seems to be a missing brace after the while, this the CFRelease is not in the same scope. Is it a copy/paste error ?

Comment: The code as presented has a syntax error, as `while` requires a statement following the condition, and the code shown has none (condition immediately followed by closing brace of outer compound statement or function/method body). I think it is too early to assess what scope anything is in until the code shown is valid.